# Why do some people delete good questions?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

When I came to stackoverflow half an hour ago, I saw that I had 50 Rep less than before. I checked what happened and saw that a question got deleted which I had answered.

The quality of the question was not bad in any means, it was about why there is a String and a StringBuffer Type in Java. It had 3 upvotes when i last read it (yesterday). And now, it is suddenly deleted.

Can anyone explain this to me? I am not yet here for so long, but I thought that a good question does not get deleted just for fun. I mean, the question was answered, and if anybody has this question again, he has to ask it again. This does not make sense at all.

Please explain this to me.

---

Link to question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262840/why-we-still-use-string-in-java

Comment: The OP cannot delete a question with more than one answer or an *upvoted* answer. Did your answer have upvotes? If you lost 50 points then it a positive score, presumably.

Comment: My answer had 5 upvotes. And yes I know that the guy who asked could not delete his question anymore. And why would he do that? I cannot provide a link because the question is gone.

Comment: @ZerO - Do you have a link to where the question used to be?  Users with +10k reputation can see the deleted post.

Comment: I do not, unfortunately

Comment: @ZerO: You'll have a link in your [Answers -> deleted recent answers page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/2988360).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262840/why-we-still-use-string-in-java/24262861#24262861

Comment: "The quality of the question was not bad in any means" - I strongly dispute that. It's unclear ("StringBuffer is more efficient" - at what?) and should have been clarified rather than answered, IMO.

Comment: Not to mention the state of the question which, if you feel it deserves answering, you could have addressed with an appropriate edit.

Comment: And why do we still use Strings in Java?

Comment: @Trilarion: put on hold as primarily religion-based.

Comment: @PlasmaHH I don't want to have the question back but I'd say that the question by itself is not so bad and worth being posed, just not here. In the same way religious discussions are sometimes the most liveliest and most interesting. Oh wait, isn't there a stackexchange for religous things...

Answer (score 7):

Your answer wasn't deleted - the entire [*question*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262840/why-we-still-use-string-in-java) was deleted.

I can tell you as the final delete vote that I did not consider this to be a good question, and felt that it was not a good example of the kinds of questions which should be asked on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Could you supply a link?

Comment: "question" is now a link to the question.

Comment: The answer... neither, unfortunately.